# How to show each button tap a different text in order to make a story telling game

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to make a "game" inside my app to show around 15-20 strings in a label, which will be updated each time I touch a button. **How should I update each time the label, with their corresponding text, coming from the same button?** And at the same time, I need to use NSTimer or similar, I don't know, in order to show 2-3 strings each tap, with fade animation each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store the strings in an array, and make a button action that updates the label to the next string in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I update each time the label, with their corresponding
>   text, coming from the same button?

You should store the strings in an array, and make a button call an action which updates the label to the next string in the array.

```
// Store the strings in an array
let storyLines = ["A long time ago...", "More story details", "The End"]

// The story starts at the first line/string
var currentLine = 0

// Attach this to your label
@IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!

// Attach your button to this function/method
@IBAction func updateStoryLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Give the label the current part of the story
    storyLabel.text = storyLines[currentLine]

    // Prepare for the next line/string
    currentLine += 1
}
```

You could then have an `NSTimer` call the `updateStoryLabel` function/method, if the user takes to long.